Pull dynamic hierarchy from another sheet
I have an excel file with two sheets, from which I want to create a template.
In sheet 1 I want to be able to insert tasks and subtasks of a project. Each tasks can have a changing number of subtasks, depending on the project. Tasks and subtasks are defined via a dropdown menu - so far so easy.
Now I want to take this list and put it into my second sheet. Depending wether it is a task or a subtask, the subsequent cell in the row should include certain formulas.
Example:



hierarchy
days
costs




task1

=sum(C3:C4)


subtask1.1
3
=B3*800


subtask1.2
1
=B4*800


task2

=sum(C6:C8)


subtask2.1
2
=B6*800


subtask2.2
6
=B7*800


subtask2.3
4
=B8*800



The cells in column C should all be automatically added, so I only have to insert values in column B. As you can see, the formaluas in the tasks cells sometimes need to "know" how many subtasks there are. Next time, the sheet is used, there could be eg. 6 tasks with 5-10 subtasks.
This is just a small example. In my file, there are a lot more columns that need to be automatically filled and formulas might already be a lot longer.
Is there a way to achieve this using standard excel tools?
If not: Is there a way to do this using vba?
(I don't know vba apart from being able to press Alt+F11 and copy-paste code)

I would have just broken down the hierarchy column into 2 separate columns column 1 would be task and column 2 would be subtask. Then it would just be a simple matter of creating a pivot table.

A formula in C2:
=IF(B2=0,SUM(C3:INDEX(C3:C$100,MATCH(0,N(+B3:B$100),0)-1)),B2*800)

Copy down as required.
If there is more than 100 rows, adjust addresses in the formula.
Assumption: for tasks column B is empty (or contains 0).

Sorry, but your assumption is not working as initially, all values in column B will be empty until filled up manually

It seems like adding an extra if condition would be sufficient to take care of empty data rows. @e-shirt, did you try this before commenting?

@e-shirt, you should fill column B manually, leaving empty cells in rows with tasks, then formulas should give expected results. I hope each subtask requires at least 1 day.

That might work technically, but it would not be working on the dumb user side. You're assuming, the user of the template will be able to remember, which entries are tasks and which are subtasks. I am looking for a more userfriendly solution, that already shows the correct type when entering sheet 2
